# How to find a specific class name of element when there are multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some DIVs on a page.  Each has 3 classes: grid_#, push_# and pull_# where `#` is an actual number.

I need to replace each class separately, i.e. remove class='grid_1' and replace it with class='grid_14'.

I'm using a select list to choose the new class.  I need the name of the old class so I can remove it.

Through trial and error, I've found that as long as an element has only one class, I can get it using

```
var old = document.getElementById('elementId');
var old_class = old.className;
```

When I try to get the class name from a DIV with multiple classes, I get nothing.  Not undefined, not object, just blank.  I've tried `var old_class = old.className[0];` among other things, but that gives me `undefined`.

The current plan is to use regex to match the old class name to a list of possible classes, giving me a var with the class name to be removed.  Being new to javascript I'm sure there is a better way to do it.  Any suggestions are more than welcome.

I've just begun this project, but you can find it [here](http://style.chouinard.me/grid/multi_grid) if it would help.

Thanks,
Mark

EDIT: Changed title of question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the class names using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129741/how-to-get-the-class-names-using-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If element has multiple classes, you need to use `split`:

```
var old = document.getElementById('elementId');
var old_class = old.className.split(' ')[0]; // first class
```

What split does is that it creates an array by splitting string (class in this case) which you can later access by its index eg `[0]` for first class.

If element has just one class, you simply use `className`:

```
var cls = old.className;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm so wrapped up in learning something new, I guess I forgot the basics of arrays.  I suppose I would have figured it out eventually, but in the midst of trying to find an answer to multiple class names I didn't realize I had been using the wrong ID to get the element in the first place.  Guess that explains why it wasn't even returning a string.  But seriously, thanks for the quick and correct answer!

Comment: I can't seem to delete the old class.  Using `$('#1').removeClass(old_class_name);` does nothing and using `old.removeClass(old_class_name);` tells me it's not a function.  I can add classes using `old.className += new_class_name;` but for some reason cannot remove a class.  Any suggestions?  forgive me if this is something obvious, I'm still quite new to javascript and jquery.  I got it to display the old class name when I select a new one from the dropdown.  And the id of the div is in fact '1'.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Mark: jQuery works on whole `class` attribute. The way you can do is `$('someID').removeClass().addClass('clases to remain')`

Comment: I'm confused.  From jQuery web site `Description: Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.`  Shouldn't I be able to simply remove the old class with `$('#1').removeClass(old_class_name);` and replace it using `$('#1').addClass(new_class_name);`?  As I said, I can add a class to the existing classes.  Are you saying that I can't remove just one of the existing classes?

Comment: This is the last time I bother you here.  This works fine when I'm removing a class name from a static div on the page (which has multiple classes).  The div I've been trying to remove the class from has been created using `document.createElement('div');`.  Could that have something to do with my problem?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Mark: Not sure it might be so, try creating with jQuery eg `$('<div />')`