# Javascript not running under div?

Tags: javascript, function, html

I'm having a problem where the Javascript (file called Javascript.js) isn't working with my php page. Here's my javascript file:

```
function weekPrice()
{
    var weekPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["paymentform"];
    var includeWeek1 = theForm.elements["includeweek1"];
    var includeWeek2 = theForm.elements["includeweek2"];
    var includeWeek3 = theForm.elements["includeweek3"];
    var includeWeek4 = theForm.elements["includeweek4"];
    var includeWeek5 = theForm.elements["includeweek5"];
    var includeWeek6 = theForm.elements["includeweek6"];
    var afterCampCare = theForm.elements["aftercampcare"];


    if(includeWeek1.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek2.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek3.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek4.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (includeWeek5.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 60;
    }
    if (includeWeek6.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 75;
    }
    if (afterCampCare.checked==true)
    {
        weekPrice= weekPrice + 2;
    }
    return weekPrice;
}
function getTotal()
{
var weekTotalPrice = weekPrice(); 
document.querySelector('input[type=hidden][name=totalprice]').value = weekTotalPrice;
document.getElementsByClassName("totalPrice")[0].innerHTML = "" + weekTotalPrice;
}
```

To connect it to my php page, I added the following to my  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"/></script>
```

This is how I use the function:

```
<li>July 8 - July 12 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July8-July12" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek1"></li>
   <li>July 15 - July 19 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July15-July19" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek2"></li>
   <li>July 22 - July 26 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July22-July26" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek3"></li>
   <li>July 29 - August 2 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="July29-August2" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek4"></li>
   <li>August 6 - August 9 ($60/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="August6-August9" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek5"></li>
  <li>August 12 - August 16 ($75/child)<input type=checkbox name="campsessions[]" value="August12-August16" onclick="getTotal()" id="includeweek6"></li>
   </ol>

   <label> <b> Include After Camp Care? </b></label> <input type="checkbox" name= "campcare" onclick="getTotal()" id="aftercampcare" /> <br /><br />
   <i> After Camp Care is available from 4pm-6pm for an additional charge of $2/hr.</i><br /><br />

      Total Price:<div class="inline totalPrice"> </div>
```

Comment: check `view page source` and check either the javascript is properly included or not by clicking on it

Comment: In Chrome right click and inspect element in the bottom right corner do you have any Red X's because if you do something is broken please post what those are.

Comment: So what isn't working exactly? What happens if you add an `alert()` call?

Comment: yeah well it failed to load a .css and a .jpeg , not a javascript doesn't mention anything about functions when I click the different selections in the radio box. And what's not working? Well it's not calculating the total price properly using the proper javascript function. This worked before on this old page I used.

Comment: Like @Dai said add `alert('test');` or `console.log('test');` inside your functions to see if they are being fired correctly.

Comment: Make sure your javascript file is included in the page before your checkboxes

Comment: yeah it is included before, it's included in the header. And when I do alert('test');, it just says the word 'test' as a popup

Comment: Maybe it's because the `div` class is "inline totalPrice" and you're `getElementsByClassName` is "totalPrice"?

Comment: yeah but when you leave a space between inline and totalPrice, doesn't that mean 2 classes? So it should still work?

Comment: Well, try it and find out

Comment: yeah, doesn't work either

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051948/how-to-find-a-specific-class-name-of-element-when-there-are-multiple-classes

Comment: Thing is, this code worked fine before with the two classes or with the one class, I just changed the php page to include tabs now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lays here, you have "opacity: 0", delete that line and it appears to work.  You may need to mess with some other styles, but thats why you're not seeing it.

You may not want to do that though because it is probably used somewhere else.  the easiest fix though is to change your "totalPrice" div to a span, that will fix the problem because it wont match the below CSS

```
.content div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    transition: all linear 0.1s;
}\
```

change it to this:

```
Total Price:<span class="totalPrice"> </span>
```