# How to get a specify class name from multiple class in a div by using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to get a class as a string from multiple class in an html element.I have many classes which stored in an html element but I want to get only class name from them.

Here is my **html:**

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4"></div>
<div class="class1 classb classv classd"></div>
<div class="class1 classw classdf classl"></div>
<div class="class1 classl classo classj"></div>
```

**jquery:**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready({

             if($(".class1").hasClass("classw")){ 
                 var cl = $(".classw").attr('class');
                 console.log(cl)// out put: class1 classw
             }
      });
</script>
```

As above code I will get **class1 classw** class But i want to get only **classw**  class of them.

Please help

Comment: I have already it you can check in if conditional

Comment: As you've checked element class using `hasClass`, why not directly use classname as string

Comment: used as string? before used we have to find it right and then will to initial to a variable right? I find more tutorial if we want to get a class string we I have to used attr in jquery so how to used as string as u said?

Comment: How you found the particular class name. If you don't know the classname?

Comment: Possibly duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051948/how-to-find-a-specific-class-name-of-element-when-there-are-multiple-classes

Comment: if($(".class1").hasClass("classw")){  can return  true/false

Comment: you don't understand what I mean. sorry may my English not good 
I mean I want to get the unique or only one class of many class inside a div to check true or false it not difficult for me because we can used hasClass in jquery

Comment: @hengsopheak code you have pasted should print **class1 classw classdf classl** ... please correct your question.

Comment: Because of this function will print all of my class name in a div that why I ask here to find the solution for get only one class as I said "s above code I will get class1 classw class But i want to get only classw class of them."

Comment: @hengsopheak How you are getting **class1 classw** !! you should get **class1 classw classdf classl**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but this will get you all the classes for each element:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4"></div>
<div class="class1 classb classv classd"></div>
<div class="class1 classw classdf classl"></div>
<div class="class1 classl classo classj"></div>

$('div.class1').each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr('class').split(' ') )
})
```

Then you can do an indexOf on the arrays that are returned:

https://jsfiddle.net/nebulousal/y8yoofd4/1/